# systemd underestimates boot time. How can I try upstart?

Tags: boot, systemd, upstart

Sorry in advance if this is a stupid question, but I'm new to this issue and every time I google it, I just get comparisons of `upstart` versus `systemd`.

Anyway, my Samsung laptop with Mint 18 is taking a long time to boot (a little over 2 min). So after googling around I found the command `systemd-analyze time` (and `blame` and etc), which say that my laptop boots in 45 seconds, which is just plain wrong.

So I searched around and in many places I heard that switching to upstart, which is more stable apparently, solved this issue.

So my questions are:

- should I try to switch to upstart (is it safe)?
- how do you switch to upstart?

At this point I'm not even sure that `systemd` and `upstart` are to be honest, and can't find this information out there since all I get are comparisons between the two.

Comment: init choice is usually tied to the distro. Unless you're using Gentoo, you're going to have to stay with systemd or switch to a distro that still uses upstart.

Comment: @drewbenn I'm doing it very approximately with my watch. How should I measure it correctly?

Comment: @drewbenn then it might be timing it correctly. Starting the timing as the Mint logo appears until the log in screen takes approximately 45 seconds. But then again, how do I speed that up? That seems like an awful lot. Both from the Mint logo to the login screen, and from logging in until actually arriving at the desktop environment. Should I change my question?

Comment: Consider getting an SSD drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if I am not pro systemd for many reasons slowness isn't one of them.

I doubt you'll get better boot time just by switching init system (except from sysVinit to something that parallelise init sequence). I guess some operation / hanging service start bump your boot time.
Maybe you should take a look at your dmesg output and syslog to check if something seems wrong.

If you have a usb 3 key with great reading perf you can try upstart by booting on a live distribution that use it like ubuntu 12.04, The result will be flawed by reading operations but in your case I don't think it's the main factor that slow down your boot time.